# How to select a single cloned element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, clone

I am dynamically adding a div to my webpage when ever I click a button.

I am doing this by cloning an original div and appending the clone.

I have the above figured out. However, within the cloned div there is a text input. I want to make sure the new clone text input is clear.

As of right now the clone carries over any text that was in the original input.

Normally the below would work.

```
$("#id").val("");
```

But, because all the divs are clones and have the same information, this would clear them all.

How do I select the exact clone whose input I want to clear?

```
//listens for when element 'addTag' is clicked -- Works
$("#addTag").click(function() {

    //clones an element 'tag' -- Work
    var clone = $("#tag").clone();

    //Attempts to change the value of clone -- Does not work
    clone.val("Value");

    // Appeneds the clone product to the end of a div -- Works
    clone.appendTo($("#tags"));

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the input-field in your cloned div and set that to nothing.

```
$(function () {
    $(".tag button").on("click", function () {
        var $tag = $(this).parent(".tag");
        var $clone = $tag.clone(true);
        $tag.after($clone);
        $clone.find("input[type='text']").val("");
    });
});
```

I set up the `var`s for your current tag-element and then clone it with the "deep clone" parameter to get the click event to be copied as well.
Then insert the clone after your current tag-element and then find your input text element and set value to "".

Good luck, hope this helps you

Here is a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wgqgtft0/1/), perhaps it can guide you to a solution.

Comment: the answer is       clone.find("input").val("");
find() being the key. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use this

```
 clone.html("<p>value</p>");
```

OR

```
 clone.text("value");
```

The `.val()` method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as `input`, `select` and `textarea`. In the case of select elements, it returns `null` when no option is selected and an array containing the value of each selected option when there is at least one and it is possible to select more because the `multiple` attribute is present.

Comment: The clone contains an input element. <div id="cloned element">  <input></input>  </div>

Comment: You want to set value in input? @seamus